# select2 not working with tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I can't get select2 to work with tags, despite copying the code that is provided exactly in the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation). Here is a basic jsfiddle with select2 that is functional: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh4Ac/

Now the only thing I change in this new example is `$("#e2").select2();` to `$("#e2").select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});`. Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh4Ac/1/

Notice that the first example works, but the second doesn't. Can someone please explain how to get tags to work for select2?

Comment: Don't know why I didn't check that first. Thanks, closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use `input` instead of `select`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Gh4Ac/2/

Comment: Support for the hidden input field has been deprecated as of v4.0 http://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#hidden-input It still works, but it's better to use a regular select field for fallback purposes.